# How to catch error when app run or program carsh

Tags: java

Hi guys here I have one doubt how can I Catch error when user run app

However how can i get error

- How to get error
- How to display in Activity

  > ```
  >     try {
  >     //code that may crash
  > } catch(Exception _e){
  >     //here do something when try detects error
  >     Log.e("try/catch error", _e.toString());
  >
  >
  > }
  > ```

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't very clear.  Can you please make a bit more easy to understand what you are asking?

Comment: e is the Exception... and the message is suggestion the reason why the app is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java supports checked and unchecked exceptions.

You should use checked exceptions for all exceptional events that you can anticipate and that a well-written application should be able to handle. A checked exception extends the Exception class. A method that throws a checked exception or that calls a method that specifies a checked exception needs to either specify or handle it.

Unchecked exceptions extend the RuntimeException. You should use them for internal errors that you can’t anticipate and that, most often, the application can’t recover from. Methods can but don’t need to handle or specify an unchecked exception. Typical examples that throw unchecked exceptions are:

```
the missing initialization of a variable which results in a NullPointerException or
the improper use of an API that causes an IllegalArgumentException
```

More on this subject could be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)